# Running python unit tests and output the results to Jenkins

Tags: python, unit-testing, jenkins

For a project using Jenkins I would like to be able to run Python Unit tests. These tests contain interactions with an embedded device. The results should be reported back to Jenkins.

My current setup (using python 2.7) looks the following

```
|
| helperModules
|-- customlogger.py
|-- settings.py
|-- serial.py
| tests
|-- test_login
|-- test_communicate_serial
| start.py
```

In the root directory I have an file called start.py, which initializes some settings like a custom logger and loading some general settings before running the unittests. The tests themselves are located in the directory test, the tests are currently based on unittest of Python, and are executed by start.py.

Since I want to run the tests and generate a report readable for Jenkins I want to know which steps I should take. Use py.test, nose or xmlrunner? Since nose will probably stopped being maintained this is not preferred. Should I use py.test, do I need to adapt my setup and try to remove start.py. The logging that I have setup in my start.py is necessary for debugging, so if I need to replace it by putting it in the testcases themselves it will change my current design, however this logging is a requirement.

Curious what your thoughts are about this, how would you proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the post I started experimenting with pytest and integrating that in the current start.py.

```
import pytest
     .
     .
pytest.main("--junitxml=\"report\test.xml\"")
```

When all setup is finished I call this pytest.main with the argument to generate the xml file. It automatically discovered my unit-tests and executed them.

It looks like the integration was easy and still keeping compatibility with my setup. Hope this answer can also help others.

Another advantage is that I can also run

```
python -m pytest --junitxml=test.xml
```

from the command line of course the setup of the logging will not take place when running the tests, but tests run which can be a nice feature.